# Rxweb - How to bind dropdown from Json data with web api

Tags: angular

Anyone know how to bind the dropdown from `JSON with web API` as shown below by using `RxWeb.` is there any other way available please let me know. Thank you

### Component

```
 serverData = [
    {
      name: "department",
      type: "select",
      //source: [{ value: 1, text: "Male" },{ value: 2, text: "Female" }],
      source: 'http://localhost:84/api/Anonymous/BindDropdown',
      ui: {
          label: 'Department',
          placeholder: 'Select',
      }
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Can you explain more your problem? did you get the JSON data and you want to bind it to your dropdown?

Comment: What i mean to say, I want to bind the dropdown from json such as (source: 'http://localhost:84/api/Anonymous/BindDropdown') instead of (source: [{ value: 1, text: "Male" },{ value: 2, text: "Female" }]) if possible.

Comment: Can you share all the whole code please of binding and how to get your data?